# How to identify proper substring length

Tags: c#, io, substring

I'm trying to read column values from this file starting at the arrow position:

[image]

***Here's my error:***

[image]

I'm guessing it's because the length values are wrong.
Say I have column with value :"Dog       " 
with the word dog and a few spaces after it. Do I have to set the length parameter as 3 (for dog) or can I set it as 6 to accommodate the spaces after Dog. This because each column length is fixed. As you can see some words are smaller than others and in order to be consistent I just want to set length as max column length (ex: 28 is length of 3rd column of my file but not all 28 spots are taken up everytime - ex:  the word client is only 6 characters long

Comment: It would help if we knew what the values of `line` and `j` were at the point of the failure.

Comment: hey how would i figure that out

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to learn how to use your tools so that you can debug simple problems by yourself. Look at the bottom of the Visual Studio window; there should be a "locals" tab that lists the current values of the local variables.

Comment: And about using SO, please post code as text and not as pictures.

Comment: values of local variables pos and len just say int[3] and line says    "0Total Records:     3,390,315" string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert Levy's answer is correct for the issue you're seeing - you've attempted to pull a substring from a string with a starting position that is greater than the length of the string.

You're parsing a fixed-length field file, where each field has a certain amount of characters, whether or not it uses all of them, and the `pos` and `len` arrays are intended to define those field lengths for use with Substring.  As long as the line you're reading matches the expected field starts and lengths, you will be ok.  As soon as you come to a line that doesn't match (for example, what appears to be the totals line - `0TotalRecords: 3,390,315`) the field length definitions you've been using won't work, as the format has changed (and the line length may not even be the same).

There are a couple of things I would change to make this work.  First, I would change your `pos` and `len` arrays so that they take the entirety of the field, not part of it. You can use `Trim()` to get rid of any leading or trailing blanks.  As defined, your first field will only take the last number of the Seq# (pos 4, len 1), and your second field will only take the first 5 characters of the field, even though it appears to have space for ~12 characters.

Take a look at this (it's hard to be exact working from the picture, but for purposes of demonstration it will work):

```
          1         2         3         4 
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890
 Seq# Field       Description
    3 BELNR       ACCOUNTING DOCUMENT NBR
```

The numbers are the position of each charcter in the line.  I would define the `pos` array to be the start of the field (0 for the first field, and then the position of the first letter of the field heading for each field after that), so you would have:

```
Seq# = 0
Field = 6
Description = 18
```

The `len` array would hold the length of the field, which I would define as the amount of characters up to the beginning of the next field, like this:

```
Seq# = 6
Field = 12
Description = 28 (using what you have as it is hard to tell
```

This would make your array initialization the following:

```
int[] pos = new int[3] { 0, 6, 18 };
int[] len = new int[3] { 6, 12, 28 };
```

If you wanted the fourth field, it would start at position 36 (pos 18 + len 28 = 36).

The second thing is I would check in the loop to see if the Total Records line is there, and skip that line (most likely it's the last line):

```
foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
{
    if (!line.Contains("Total Records"))
    {
        val[j] = line.Substring(pos[j], len[j]).Trim();
    }
}
```

Another way to do this would be to modify the original query and add a `TakeWhile` clause to it to only take lines until you hit the Total Records one:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName).Skip(8)
                 .TakeWhile(l => !l.Contains("Total Records")).ToArray();
```

The above would skip the first 8 lines and take all the remaining lines up to, but not including, the first line to contain "Total Records" in the string.

Then you could do something like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName).Skip(8)
                 .TakeWhile(l => !l.Contains("Total Records")).ToArray();
textBox1.Lines = lines;

int[] vale = new int[3];
int[] pos = new int[3] { 0, 6, 18 };
int[] len = new int[3] { 6, 12, 28 };

foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
{
    val[j] = line.Substring(pos[j], len[j]).Trim();
}
```

Now you don't have to check for the "Total Records" line.

Of course, if there are other lines in your file, or there are records after the "Total Records" line (which I rather doubt) you'll have to handle those cases as well.

In short, the code for pulling out the substrings will only work for lines that match that particular format (or more specifically, have fields that match those positions/lengths) - anything outside out of that will either give you incorrect values or throw an error (if the start position is greater than the length of the string).

Answer (score 2):

that exception is complaining about the *first* parameter which suggests that your file contains a row that is < 18 characters

Comment: The first parameter is position so how could it complain saying a row is  <18 characters when position can by any number in the whole row (the rows have a lot more characters than 18 dont they)

Comment: apparently one of your lines doesnt have more than 18 characters.  that's what the exception message is clearly telling you.  inspect what 'line' is when the exception hits to see this for yourself

Comment: This is the value for line:    "0Total Records:     3,390,315" string

The loop doesn't even initiate by the looks of this

Comment: sorry, i dont think you are using the debugger correctly.  the exception message is very clear and its happening inside the loop (so the loop is most certainly running)

Comment: I'm in the bottom left tab which says "Local" under that it gives me variable values - Do you want to see my actual program file